# Odd and Even Fourier Series Extension of $f(x)=x$ on $[0,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm confused on finding the odd and even extensions of $f(x) = x$ on $[0,\pi]$. I know the general forms and how to find the co-efficients, but for the sin series, $f(0)$ =/= $f(\pi)$, so then I only have $f(x)$ related to its extension, not equal to it (Thm: Suppose $f(x)$ is a piecewise smooth on the interval $0\le x\le L$.  The Fourier sine series of $f(x)$ will be continuous and will converge to $f(x)$ on the interval provided $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval and $f(0)=0=f(L)$ . So, I would have a discontinuity jump, but I'm not sure how to represent it and apply it. Without it, I have the odd extension  $f(x) = x \backsim \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(nx)(-2/n)(\cos(n \pi))$ and the even extension is $f(x) = x=\pi/2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(nx)(2/(\pi n^2))\cos(n\pi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your hypotheses, and for the function $f(x)=x$, the Fourier series of sines is equal to $f$ everywhere, except at $x=\pi$, where it is $0$ (as you can check explicitly, at this point, simply substituting $x=\pi$ in the series that you already wrote).

More generally, the Fourier series of sines of a function $f$ with the hypotheses that you described ("piecewise smooth", although strictly speaking one should be more rigorous, as Dirichlet deserves) is zero both at $x=0$ and at $x=\pi$, and is equal to $f$ on all other points.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Does that mean I can get rid of the relation symbol and explicitly write an equals sign? Also, what does that mean, then, for the even extension, where they aren't the same when n is odd?

Comment: For an arbitrary "piecewise smooth" function you can indeed write $F=f$, where $F$ is either the series of sines or of cosines, **for all points other than $0$ and $\pi$**. Of course, all this is the same for functions on other intervals.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to write the series so that it is able to incorporate the boundary points if the function does not take on the same value at both ends?

Comment: No, the series are really like that. :)